# Will PBS air full-length episodes of Sherlock Series 3 in the US?

Tags: sherlock

When *Sherlock* originally aired in the United States as part of PBS's *Masterpiece*, each episode was edited down to an hour, from the original 80-90 minute length.  Will series 3 be similarly edited? Or will PBS air each full-length episode?

Comment: *"each episode was edited down to an hour"* - What, really? Who on earth would do that?

Comment: **I hope not!** I am encouraged by the fact that my local PBS station has allotted 2 hours for the first episode on January 19th:
http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/masterpiece/programs/episode/sherlock-s3-e1-empty-hearse/ Note that the episode is listed as being 120 minutes. Now, not saying they couldn't edit it down to an hour and then stuff it full of promos (God, I hope it's not pledge drive season), but I am holding out hope.

Comment: @ChristianRau I believe there is a bill working its way in Congress making it illegal to edit Sherlock episodes, but it hasn't passed yet.

Comment: @splatteredbits are you serious?

Comment: According to producer (and Steven Moffat's wife) Sue Vertue [8 minutes per episode were cut](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/tv/news/sherlock-holmes-and-the-mystery-of-the-missing-eight-minutes-7738001.html) in series 2: `We had to cut eight minutes. The PBS episodes have to be 82 minutes because of sponsors announcements.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I watched the shows on the PBS broadcast. Each *Masterpiece* episode was allotted 2 hours - 90 minutes of that episode of *Sherlock*, followed by a 30 minute "Behind the scenes" type show about the episode that just aired.

So to your questions:

No, the episodes were not edited, and

Yes, PBS aired each full-length episode.

Comment: I can confirm this is what happened.

Answer (score 1):

I just finished watching all three episodes on the www.pbs.org web site.  All three episodes were approximately 90 minutes each.